# Android Display MainActivity with Google Maps after SplashScreen

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My App keeps crashing all the time and i actually can't figure out why!
I have two Activities: SplashScreen.java and MainActivity.java
And two layouts: activity_main.xml for MapView and activity_splash_screen.xml for the SplashScreen.

What happens is following: I run the Application -> SplashScreen loads and displays but than the App Crashes.

Maybe someone of you guys can help me out or knows any Tutorials that could help me. If you need more Informations let me know please.

**This is my MainActivity:**

```
    package me.resq.resqme;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// Constant for defining latitude and longitude
static final LatLng DerekPos = new LatLng(40 , -79);

// GoogleMap class
private GoogleMap googleMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // verify we can interact with the Google Map
    try {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().
                    findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        }
        // Show a satellite map with roads
        /* MAP_TYPE_NORMAL: Basic map with roads.
        MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE: Satellite view with roads.
        MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN: Terrain view without roads.
        */
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        // Place dot on current location
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Turns traffic layer on
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);

        // Enables indoor maps
        googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);

        // Turns on 3D buildings
        googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);

        // Show Zoom buttons
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        // Create a marker in the map at a given position with a title
        Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().
                position(DerekPos).title("Sie sind hier!"));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

    }
```

**This is my SplashScreen:**

```
     package me.resq.resqme;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

private static int SPLASH_SCREEN_DELAY = 3000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Executed after timer is finished (Opens MainActivity)
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            // Kills this Activity
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_SCREEN_DELAY);
}
}
```

In my activity_main.xml i use a MapFragment to display the map:

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Logcat displays me this after crashing, but i cant figure out whats wrong:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{me.resq.resqme/me.resq.resqme.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error
>   inflating class fragment
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2328)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366)
>               at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2031)
>               at me.resq.resqme.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that  is in the  element of
>   AndroidManifest.xml
>               at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ad.a(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.a.e.a(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.h.onTransact(SourceFile:62)
>               at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
>               at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ah.b(SourceFile:179)
>               at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(SourceFile:100)
>               at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ag.onTransact(SourceFile:62)
>               at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
>               at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzc$zza$zza.zzt(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zzb.zzxL(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onInflate(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
>               at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4996)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366)
>               at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2031)
>               at me.resq.resqme.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> API key not found. Check that is in the element of AndroidManifest.xml

Seems, the API key for map service is missing in your manifest file.

Go to [Google Maps for Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/) and click 'GET A KEY'

Comment: '<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDLq5tmEkL.....rest of key" />'

I have this in my manifest file

Comment: The <meta-data> must be placed within <application></application>, not outside. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#add_the_api_key_to_your_application

Comment: Works now. Thanks alot mate :)